# Mapping domain entity and some list to Dto object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

I want to using modelMapper because domain entity match to dto object. But there is some problems. 
In the dto object, it has some array list like orderList, codeList....

It is my code

This are example codes of user, userDto, userServiceImpl comparing to my objects and service.

```java
// it is my User domain
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer seq;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="role_seq")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
}

// it is my UserDto
@Data
public class UserDto {
    private Integer userSeq;
    private Integer roleSeq;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Integer> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> codeList = new ArrayList<>();
}

// and Last it is service layer
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Override
    public UserDto getUserDto(Integer userSeq) {
        User user = userRepository.findBySeq(userSeq);
        List<UserCode> userCodeList = userCodeRepository.findAllByUserSeqOrderByOrderNoAscNullsLast(userSeq);

        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        UserDto userDto = modelMapper.map(user, UserDto.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < userCodeList.size(); i++) {
            userDto.getOrderList().add(userCodeList.get(i).getOrderNo()); // I don't like this code...
            userDto.getCodeSeqList().add(userCodeList.get(i).getCode().getCodeName()); // I don't like this code too...
        }

        PropertyMap<User, UserDto> userToUserDtoPropertyMap = new PropertyMap<User, UserDto>() {
            protected void configure() {
                map().setUserSeq(source.getSeq());
                map().setRoleSeq(source.getRole().getSeq()); // I don't know why it is not mapping...
            }
        };
        modelMapper.addMappings(userToUserDtoPropertyMap);

        return userDto;
    }
}
```

In the example, there is just two list, but in my codes 7 lists.
I want to use only mapper not "get and add".
please help me... how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsonignoreproperties annotation to ignore the missing properties in your DTO. So it will populate only those properties which are available in both. Please check the below URL which is using ObjectMapper for the same purpose.
https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/entity-object-conversion-to-dto-object.html

Comment: this way is not for me... because there are some list in my dto, but not in domain.

Answer (score -2):

In USER Entity

```
{
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private List<Address> address;
}
```

In USERDTO

```
{
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
private String id;
private String email;
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private List<Address> address;
}
```

IN Controller or Service layer (Use BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, userDto))

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-new-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> createNewUserAndSendEmail(@RequestBody SignUpDto signUpDto) {
    User user = new User();
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(signUpDto, user);
    user = userService.createNewUserAndSendEmail(user);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, userDto);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userDto);
}
```

In Service layer

```
//Generate a new user and send email
    public User createNewUserAndSendEmail(User user) {
        if (user != null && utilService.checkUserAvailability(user.getEmail()) == false) {
            user = User.initFrom(user);
            userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
            String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateTokenWithPinAndEmail(user);
            String emailBody = AppConstant.EMAIL_VERIFICATION_BODY + token;
            emailService.sendEmail(user.getEmail(), AppConstant.EMAIL_VERIFICATION_SUBJECT, emailBody);
            user.setPasswordVerifiedCode(emailBody);
            return user;
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestException("The Request Cannot Be Fulfilled Due To Bad Syntax Exception.");
        }
    }
```

These 2 static methods are in user entity but call-in service layer.

```
public static User initFrom(User user) {
        user.setPassword(UtilService.bCryptPassword(user.getPassword()));
        user.setId("USER-" + UtilService.generateFourDigitCode());
        user.setStatus(AppConstant.PENDING);
        user.setEmailVerifiedCode(UtilService.generateRandomString());
        user.setIsEmailVerified(false);
        user.setProvider(AppConstant.PROVIDER_GENERAL);
        user.setRole(AppConstant.PENDING);
        return user;
    }

    public static List<UserDto> fromUsersToUserDtoList(List<User> users) {
        List<UserDto> userDtos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (User user : users) {
            UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, userDto);
            userDtos.add(userDto);
        }
        return userDtos;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't the answer I want. I want to use modelMapper. But more importantly, My Dto Object is not same my domain. In my User Domain, there isn't arraylist. but In my Dto object, there is....